# Can't connect to wifi with laptop

Tags: wireless-networking, laptop

I can't connect to wifi with my laptop but I can connect to wifi with my phone, ps3 and ipod etc. I can actually connect to the internet with my laptop when I use a cable to connect to the router. Does anyone know what my problem is?

My connection worked perfectly before, but 3 days ago it just stopped working.
I have windows 8.
In the corner it just gives me a perfect bar connection and I cant find any solution on internet.

Thank you

Comment: I actually think my laptop is the problem. Because my phone can connect to wireless network...

Comment: @DaveRook Yes I could connect via wireless before. 3 days ago it just stopped working...

Comment: @DaveRook Done what I could in my edit now.

Comment: That is now a better question. +1

Comment: Does the OS detect the wireless adapter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few options and things to try I think

[A repair of the network adapter](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows-8/fix-network-adapter-problems)

[A System Restore](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows-8/restore-refresh-reset-pc)

Comment: This didn't work. Just done a System Restore.

Comment: OW WAIT Now it works! Thank you very much! I tried some things my self as well but I have no idea what fixed it but it could be your solution so thanks anyway.

Comment: It's a pleasure. Remember, if you do ask another question, please provide as much information as possible, it usually means more responses :)

Comment: Just restarted my laptop and it doesn't work anymore... :S EDIT: It worked again when I plugged in the cable for a second... :(

Comment: Try disabling the firewall and any anti virus (AV). This means that the settings are correct (ie the connection is set up with the correct password), we just need to find out why it falls over.. Also, use MSCONFIG to make sure no programs are loading which shouldn't be

Answer (score 0):

You could rule out that it is a hardware problem if you use a linux live cd and try to connect to the network with this. When you can see your network it is almost sure that your problem comes from drivers or configuration.

It could also be helpful to see if the hardware is still listed in the control panel.

If you are not successful you could try to get your laptop repaired (if it is new enough to have warranty) or use wifi via an USB stick or PCI express card. Maybe you can borrow one before buying to see if this solves your problem.

Comment: I dont use a linux live cd. My hardware is still listed in control panel

Comment: @loko I know that you don't usually use it. I just said you can [download](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/try-ubuntu-before-you-install) one and boot from usb or cd without installation and see if it works from there.